# How do I make an integer go up and display on a JLabel?

Tags: java, integer, jlabel

I know this may sound like a stupid question, but I cannot figure this out.  I'm pretty new to java, and here's my code:

```
if (e.getSource() == Game1){
         wins++;
         Wins.setText(wins+"/30 endings completed!");
        /* Game1 g1 = new Game1();
        g1.Game1();*/
    }
```

I thought this would work, but it didn't.  Here's what I get when I run the code:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
at WindowObject.actionPerformed(WindowObject.java:92)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

If anyone can help me, I will be very grateful, thanks.

Comment: Suppose `Wins` is `null`. Check it with debug

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that Integer win is not null. I do see one reason behind NPE is that win is null and you are saying win++ on a null object. During doing ++, while autoboxing, it will throw NPE.

also

Make sure JLabel is not null. If you are calling a method on a null object, it will throw NPE.

Either Integer win or JLabel Win is null or both are null. Else I don't see any reason behind NPE.

Comment: Like I said, I'm new to java, so I don't know what you mean when you say 'you can just new the variable.

Comment: I mean just make sure that win and Win are not null. Just for validation, do win = new Interger(1234) and see if you are able to see this 1234 on your JLabel